# docker-compose run web bundle exec rails db:migrateエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

質問です。

[DockerでRails + MySQLの開発環境をつくる手順](https://qiita.com/jshimazu/items/ba13ce87dfdb11e2d1d9)
[Quickstart: Compose and Rails](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/)
を見てここでも色々教えていただき

GCPでもdocker-composeできましたが

`docker-compose run web rake db:create`

`docker-compose run web bin/rails g scaffold User name:string`

`docker-compose run web bundle exec rails db:migrate`

の最後をしたところ

```
Creating network "root_default" with the default driver
Creating root_db_1 ...
Creating root_db_1 ... done
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:89:in `connect'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:89:in `initialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:21:in `new'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:21:in `mysql2_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:759:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:803:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:782:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:743:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:500:in `checkout'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:in `connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:931:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:116:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:88:in `connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:20:in `table_exists?'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:24:in `create_table'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1125:in `initialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1007:in `new'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1007:in `up'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:985:in `migrate'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:171:in `migrate'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

のエラーがでるのですが....
最後の部分教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 質問したいのはGCPの挙動ですか、それともWindowsなどの環境で成功するかどうかですか？

Comment: Windowsなどの環境で成功するかどうかです

Comment: @GABAKUGIK さん、お疲れさまでした。自己解決した場合、スタック・オーバーフローでは[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)を推奨しています。質問と回答を分けることで見やすくなり、また、別個に信用度を得ることができますので、是非お願いいたします :)

Comment: 直しました。教えてくれてありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCP上に下記の順番で実施した所、エラーも無く生成できました。
また、MAC上にも同様に生成できました。

1. GCPのインスタンス生成
2. docker,docker-composeのインストール。
3. [DockerでRails + MySQLの開発環境をつくる手順](https://qiita.com/jshimazu/items/ba13ce87dfdb11e2d1d9)を順番に実施。
4. port 3000のfirewallの設定

Answer (score 0):

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - '3316:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./db/mysql/volumes:/var/lib/mysql

  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

で直りました。
ありがとうございました。